# Регулярное выражение проверяющее пользовательский ввод

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярное выражение для проверки отсутствия определенных символов в строке например: мне необходимо исключить ввод букв русского алфавита, "\", "/". заранее спасибо
P.S. пробовал что то типа этого [^А-я\/] строка 123.456-789 не проходит проверку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[^А-ЯЁа-яё\\/]+$
```

Но вообще, сама идея неверна. Нет смысла запрещать русские буквы - юникод большой - там всякое найдётся, в том числе буквы других алфавитов. Чем не угодил именно русский? Вероятно, надо *разрешать* только цифры, латинские буквы и некоторый набор спецсимволов (типа точек, дифисов и т. д.).

Comment: русский не угодил тем что из данной строки текста формируется имя файла, а там где используется данный файл нет поддержки русского языка. да Вы правы насчет всего остального.я подумал что проще запретить некоторый набор символов ввиду того что их меньше чем описывать разрешенные

Comment: (1) Зачем отметки начала и конца строки? Ведь тогда `Hi, i am Доктор!` пройдёт проверку.
(2) Обратный слэш не ищется.

Comment: @TheDoctor наоборот, *иначе* оно пройдет: https://regex101.com/r/yD1jQ4/1

Comment: а разве нельзя использовать конструкцию так: "^[^А-яёЁ\/\\]+$" вроде же работает коректно?!почему все пишут двумя диапазонами(верхний/нижний регистр)?

Comment: @TheDoctor (1) Наоборот. Без них хватит любого симвлола не из набора. (2) Действительно, забыл его заэкранировать. Поправил.

Comment: @Bald56rus "почему все пишут двумя диапазонами(верхний/нижний регистр)?" - потому что эти символы разных регистров не идут подряд - между ними полно всего. Можно было бы вместо этого указать флаг нечувствительности к регистру (и, пожалуй, стоило бы), но без указания, о каком языке идёт речь, это проблематично, поэтому в лоб - оба регистра в регулярку.

Answer (score 0):

Не пройдёт ваша строка из-за того, что в ней спецсимволы есть.
Юзай [preg_quote](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-quote.php).

Исключить русский алфавит, слэш и обратный слэш можно как-то так:

```
[а-яёА-ЯЁ\/\\]+
```

Если завопит - значит есть запрещённые символы.